# Проигрывание музыкального файла в for-in Swift

Tags: swift

Доброе время суток, я новичок в SWIFT, что я пытаюсь сделать так это проигревания музыкального файла в for-in. Как я понел по тому коду что я написал то в SWIFT не предусмотрено возможнасть из for-in перейдя в функцию сначала пройти по тому коду а по окончанию вернуться в for-in и продолжать то для чего конструкция for-in созданна. Мой код:

```
            for words in AppEngine.linesWords{
            labelText.text = String(words)
            TTS_Converter(TTS_To_Convert: words)
            for oneCharater in words{
                labelText.text = String(oneCharater)
                MPlayer.sharedInstance.playItem(audioFile: String(oneCharater))
                print(oneCharater)
            }
            labelText.text = String(words)
            TTS_Converter(TTS_To_Convert: words)
        }
```